# Hi....Can someone help me with getting TWITTER_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN from twitter developer portal

Tags: twitter, sdk

I am trying to create a tweet  and follow a twitter account from springboot application.I am using twitter-api-java-sdk.

```
TwitterApi apiInstance = new TwitterApi();
TwitterCredentialsOAuth2 credentials = new 
TwitterCredentialsOAuth2(System.getenv("TWITTER_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID"),
      System.getenv("TWITTER_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET"),
      System.getenv("TWITTER_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN"),
      System.getenv("TWITTER_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN"));
apiInstance.setTwitterCredentials(credentials);
```

from where will I get TWITTER_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN?

Comment: The refresh token would typically be issued alongside the access token when completing the authentication. did you pass in the `offline.access` scope when initially authenticating? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your response....I couldn't find a place for setting offline access..I tried with creating  two accounts